# Ocean-Unit testing

Tags: .net, nunit, ocean

When I try to run the Unit testing sample from the Ocean SDK, I get an error when I try to load the dll in the NUnit.exe.
Can anyone help on what could be the reason?

Exception below from NUnit.exe:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException...

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, RuntimeTypeHandle* methodInstArgs, Int32 methodInstCount)
   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandle(Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext)
   at System.Reflection.Module.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken, Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(CustomAttributeRecord caRecord, MetadataImport scope, Assembly& lastAptcaOkAssembly, Module decoratedModule, MetadataToken decoratedToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, Object[] attributes, IList derivedAttributes, RuntimeType& attributeType, RuntimeMethodHandle& ctor, Boolean& ctorHasParameters, Boolean& isVarArg)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(Module decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList derivedAttributes)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeType type, RuntimeType caType, Boolean inherit)
   at System.RuntimeType.GetCustomAttributes(Type attributeType, Boolean inherit)
   at NUnit.Core.CoreExtensions.InstallAdhocExtensions(Assembly assembly)
   at NUnit.Core.Builders.TestAssemblyBuilder.Load(String path)
   at NUnit.Core.Builders.TestAssemblyBuilder.Build(String assemblyName, Boolean autoSuites)
   at NUnit.Core.Builders.TestAssemblyBuilder.Build(String assemblyName, String testName, Boolean autoSuites)
   at NUnit.Core.TestSuiteBuilder.BuildSingleAssembly(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Core.TestSuiteBuilder.Build(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Core.SimpleTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Core.ProxyTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Core.ProxyTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Core.RemoteTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.PrivateProcessMessage(RuntimeMethodHandle md, Object[] args, Object server, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at NUnit.Core.TestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Util.TestDomain.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Util.TestLoader.LoadTest(String testName)
```

Comment: we got rid of this message by putting all the NUnit assemblies and Ocean dlls in the Extensions folder. But now we get an error whenw e run it.
at System.Reflection.Module._GetTypesInternal(StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
at Slb.Ocean.Petrel.Testing.PetrelEngine.InitializeInstance()
at Slb.Ocean.Petrel.Testing.PetrelEngine.get_Instance()
at UnitTestDemo.AssemblySetUp.RunBeforeAnyTests() in C:\Program Files\Schlumberger\Ocean 2011\Samples\UnitTesting\UnitTest\AssemblySetup.cs:line 30

Answer (score 4):

This case was already solved via Ocean Dev. Portal, as we found, it's really important to follow (attentively) all instructions in sample's readMe file, for example, "Make sure you have the additional testing assemblies copyed to the petrel root" – means not only NUnit root's DLLs but also lib-subfolder. There are two "not-clear" points were found: 1) ProbingPath in nunit.exe.config has to be extended by ProbingPath from Petrel but not replaced and 2) for some reason user may need to copy content of NUnit "framework" subfolder into Petrel root too.

Comment: This approach doesn't seem to work with Petrel/Ocean 2013, does it ?

Comment: I'm not inside Ocean team anymore, but as I know, from 2013 release, Ocean has an "integrated" NUnit engine, if you have a chance, please take a look at Ocean Developers Guide, Volume 11: "Licensing, Deployment, and Unit Testing" for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, the "Enable shadow copy" option of NUnit is checked on. This option should be toggled off, so that files necessary for running tests will be copied to Petrel root folder.